# Regex for sorting Java versions

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I want to sort the array of Java versions asc or desc. I m looking for a regex pattern which can be used for solving. Please let me know if anyone can help.

> Eg arr: ['1.4.2_01', '1.4.11_01', '1.8.0_131', '1.6.0_45', '1.8.0_72', '9.2.4', '9.0.1']

Comment: [Java or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: Any language is fine

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use :

```
String arr[] = {"1.4.2_01", "1.8.0_131", "1.6.0_45", "1.8.0_72", "9.2.4", "9.0.1"};
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

**Output**

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
[1.4.2_01, 1.6.0_45, 1.8.0_131, 1.8.0_72, 9.0.1, 9.2.4]
```

Comment: are you sur @FrankRoth which version should be firt `1.8.2.7..` or `1.8.0.1..` ?

Comment: Not sure where your 2 versions occur, but. `1.8.2.7` > `1.8.0.1`.

Comment: No it isn't. This should be the right order:`[1.4.2_01, 1.6.0_45, 1.8.0_72, 1.8.0_131 9.0.1, 9.2.4]`

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it by the following implementation:

```
var versions = ["1.4.2_01", "1.6.0_45", "1.8.0_72", "1.8.0_131", "9.0.1", "9.2.4"];

var compare = function(v1,v2){

   v1splitted = v1.split('_');
   v2splitted = v2.split('_');

   if(v1splitted[0] === v2splitted[0]){
       if(parseInt(v1splitted[1]) > parseInt(v2splitted[1])){
           return 1;
       }
       return -1;
   }

    return (v1 > v2) ? 1 : -1 
}

var sortedVersions = versions.sort(compare);
// ["1.4.2_01", "1.6.0_45", "1.8.0_72", "1.8.0_131", "9.0.1", "9.2.4"]
```

Comment: Hi Frank thanks for the answer. This is not working for the following array ['1.4.2_01', '1.4.11_01', '1.8.0_131', '1.6.0_45', '1.8.0_72', '9.2.4', '9.0.1']. I have updated the question.